# Как из даты вычитать время?

Tags: python, datetime

Мне нужно из даты вычесть время.

Код:

```
import datetime
open = datetime.datetime.strptime('9:00:00', '%H:%M:%S')
now = datetime.datetime.now()
trading_open = now - open
print(trading_open)
#44655 days, 13:15:19.032548
```

Есть ли возможность получить разницу в часах и минутах?

Comment: Если ответ устраивает, поставьте галку она ниже верхнего и нижнего треугольника.

Answer (score 2):

Дело в том, что строка

```
open = datetime.datetime.strptime('9:00:00', '%H:%M:%S')
```

возвращает '1900-01-01 09:00:00'
Установил дату с днем, месяцем и годом, теперь все как нужно.

```
import datetime

open = datetime.datetime.strptime('05.04.2022 9:00:00', '%d.%m.%Y %H:%M:%S')
now = datetime.datetime.now()
trading_open = now - open
print(trading_open)
```

Если не знаем даты, то можно попробовать поставить текущую:

```
import datetime
from datetime import date

open = datetime.datetime.strptime(str(date.today()) + ' 9:00:00', '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')
now = datetime.datetime.today()
trading_open = now - open
print(trading_open)
```

Разница создает объект 'datetime.timedelta' а с ним не так просто. Но вам же нужен не стандартный вариант. Поэтому получаем следующее.
Вообщем из 'trading_open' делаю строку и если есть разница в один день, то ищу после запятой плюс пробел, извлекаю только строку часов и минут. Меня одно смущает. Вы точно уверены, что текущее время будет браться после 9 часов, если до то будут минусовые значения?

```
open = datetime.datetime.strptime(str(date.today()) + ' 9:00:00', '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')
now = datetime.datetime.today()
trading_open = now - open
ttt = str(trading_open)

start = ttt.find(",")
fine = ttt.rfind(":")
if start > 0:
    start+=1
else:
    start = 0

print(ttt[start:fine])
```

Comment: Дело в том, что получить точную дату open (05.04.2022) не получается. Есть ли способ именно время вычитать из даты, или же как-то автоматом подставлять дату?

Comment: Вы имеете ввиду пределах дня(часы и минуты)?

Comment: Да, больше дня диапазон составлять не будет

Comment: Обновил сообщение поставил текущую дату. Так подойдет?

Comment: date.today() - откуда date взялось? Если там имелось ввиду datetime.datetime.today(), то я уже попробовал - выдает ошибку
ValueError: unconverted data remains: .239708 9:00:00

Comment: Все работает с date.today() , вы наверное пробел перед 9 часом не поставили. Копируйте весь код я его обновил. Немного еще посмотрю, мне кажется есть вариант проще.

Comment: проверил, все работает, но есть одна загвоздка. Выдает 14:39:40.360147, и это не совсем то, что мне нужно. В моем случае мне нужно получать 9 часов и 20 минут, как это реализовать?

Comment: То есть по факту мне нужно находить разницу между сейчас и 9 часами

Comment: Вам большое спасибо за ответ, некоторую часть кода заюзал вашу, но мой вопрос был скорее всего не корректен, ибо код который мне был нужен я отмечу за правильный под вопросом) Спасибо за уделенное время!

Answer (score 1):

"Что-то я делаю не так" - вы из сегодняшнего для вычитаете 9 утра 1 января 1900 года.
Отладочная печать с выводом отдельно now и open помогла бы понять причину.

```
import datetime
open = datetime.datetime.strptime('9:00:00', '%H:%M:%S')
now = datetime.datetime.now()
print(now)  #2022-04-06 22:30:59.971048
print(open) #1900-01-01 09:00:00 
trading_open = now - open
print(trading_open)
#44655 days, 13:30:59.971048
```

Answer (score 0):

Отвечаю на свой вопрос (которые не совсем корректен)

```
import pytz
import datetime

tz_moscow = pytz.timezone("Europe/Moscow")

now = datetime.datetime.now(tz_moscow)
current_time = now.strftime("%Y-%m-%d")

now = now.strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M')
now = datetime.datetime.strptime(now, '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M')
now = tz_moscow.localize(now)

open = datetime.datetime.strptime(current_time + ' 9:00', '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M')
open = tz_moscow.localize(open)

open1 = open - now
print(open1)
#выводит разницу московского(сейчас) и 9 часами (также по Москве)
```